# Make variable data type accept all UIViewController subclass

Tags: ios, swift

So I have many buttons, maybe up to 12, which is populated from a `ForEach` loop. And when each one is clicked, the button index will be passed as parameter to a function which will present a new ViewController based on the index of the button.

```
ForEach(0...11, id: \.self){ index in
    Button {
        openController(index: index)
    }, label: {
        Text("Button \(index)")
    }
}
```

Now in my `openController` function, I want to make my code as short as possible. So I will make a `switch` statement to determine the button clicked and open the respective viewcontroller.

So here's where my question comes in... I want to create just one variable which will be initialized by the respective Viewcontroller. But the problem comes when I declare the variable and try to initialize it.

For instance, since all the ViewControllers are subclasses of the `UIViewController`, I tried to declare the variable with a `UIViewController` data type before initializing it

```
func openController(index: Int){
    var viewController: UIViewController // declaring the variable
    switch index {
        case 0:
            viewController = ZeroViewController
        case 1:
            viewController = OneViewController
        // And it keeps going on till case 11
    }
    self.present(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

But I will be getting errors if I do that saying that I can't convert `viewController` which is of `UIViewController` type to `ZeroViewController`

So this will make my code bulky, because I'll have to create a variable for every Viewcontroller and also present it differently making my code look like this

```
func openController(index: Int){
    switch index {
        case 0:
            let viewController = ZeroViewController
            self.present(viewController, animated: true)
        case 1:
            let viewController = OneViewController
            self.present(viewController, animated: true)
        // And it keeps going on till case 11
    }
}
```

So is that the only option or is there a way I can shorten my code to look like the first function?

Comment: What is the initializer of your view controllers? It should be fine if you use viewController = ZeroViewController() or ZeroViewController(with any other initializer).

Comment: Can you share a sample of your view controllers?

Comment: There's a huge difference between `let viewController = ZeroViewController`
and 
`let viewController = ZeroViewController()`
You have to use the later to instantiate the object.  The `let viewController = ZeroViewController` won't even pass the compilation. So this question is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you will also be setting properties in your "destination" view controllers...

If we have these two controllers:

```
class ZeroViewController: UIViewController {
    var testZero: String = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        print("test Zero:", testZero)
    }
}

class OneViewController: UIViewController {
    var testOne: String = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        print("test One:", testOne)
    }
}
```

You can write your func like this:

```
func openController(index: Int) {
    var vc: UIViewController!
    switch index {
    case 0:
        let viewController = ZeroViewController()
        viewController.testZero = "Hello"
        vc = viewController
    case 1:
        let viewController = OneViewController()
        viewController.testOne = "Goodbye"
        vc = viewController
        // And it keeps going on till case 11
    default:
        return
    }
    self.present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

So, inside each `case`:

- instantiate a view controller *of the specific controller class*
- set any properties specific to that class
- assign a reference to that instance to the `vc` var
- then present `vc`